# How to Build proper database for Expense Manament Application build using Nodejs,Angular and MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mean-stack

I am building a Web Application named Expense Manager which shows the expenses and income resp as most app have. 
However I am into a situation where i have built signup and login mechanism but I am having difficulty in building the expense database in MongoDb?

Can anyone suggest how can I build this type of Complicated database.

Suggestion of Idea would be preferable because coding I can do.